# Unable to store parsed items as dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

I've written a tiny script in python using BeautifulSoup to parse some items out of some element stored within `content` variable within the below script. I do not wish to append items to the previously created empty dictionary; rather, i wish to parse it on the fly. However, I tried but could not achieve that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<table class="data">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="blue">
            <td>hot</td>
            <td>cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>night</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
for items in soup.select('tr'):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select("td")]
    dict_val = {data[0] : data[1]}
    print(dict_val)
```

The way I'm getting the output:

```
{'hot': 'cold'}
{'day': 'night'}
```

The way I expect to have the output:

```
{'hot': 'cold','day': 'night'}
```

Comment: Hint: `dict_val` is a new dictionary created on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary outside the for-loop:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
d = {}
for items in soup.select('tr'):
   data = [item.text for item in items.select("td")]
   d[data[0]] = data[1]
print(d)
```

Or, you can create a dictionary in one line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = [i.text for i in soup(content, 'lxml').findAll('td')]
new_s = dict([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)])
```

Output:

```
{u'hot': u'cold', u'day': u'night'}
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary comprehension. `{s[i]: s[i+1] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)}`

Comment: Did you run your newest version to verify that it works?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a computer will only do exactly what you tell it to. Your original code has this line:

```
dict_val = {data[0] : data[1]}
```

This creates a new dictionary every time the loop iterates. If instead, you want to create a single dictionary and add elements to it, you need to do just that. Often it helps to write out the steps in words:

```
create a dictionary
for each row in the table:
    parse the <td> elements from the row
    add an entry to the dictionary
```

Most of this you have already translated into Python. The key differences are where the dictionary is created and how the data from the HTML is inserted into the dictionary. I will leave the details of how to do this in Python as an exercise. (Hint: look at the other answer.) The important thing here is thinking clearly about the order of the steps you want to perform and **then** figuring out how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the dictionary before the for loop, in your code in every iteration a new dictionary is being created in this line `dict_val = {data[0] : data[1]}`. You can try the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<table class="data">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="blue">
            <td>hot</td>
            <td>cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>night</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
dict_val = {}
for items in soup.select('tr'):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select("td")]
    dict_val[data[0]] = data[1]
print(dict_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nth-child with bs4 4.7.1 and a dictionary comprehension. Solution specific to example as shown.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<table class="data">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="blue">
            <td>hot</td>
            <td>cold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>night</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
result = {k.text:v.text for (k,v) in zip(soup.select('.data  tr:nth-child(odd) td'), soup.select('.data  tr:nth-child(even) td'))}
```